# Date object trouble

Tags: java, android, datetime

Is is possible to have a date object with only time value and no date value? if yes please give a hint how?

I did this:

```
String time = "15:30:18";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(time);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(date));
```

The Above System.out.println gives correct value. bt i need it as a date object not as string

Thanks in advance

Comment: ya its possible try to search simpledateformat

Answer (score 3):

`Date` instance holds full representation to present any point of time upto millisecond, but if you just want time from it you could use `SimpleDateFormat` to just print the time portion

```
String timeRepresentation  = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS").format(dateInstance);
```

**See**

- [Demo](http://ideone.com/KTevq)
- [`SimpleDateFormat` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: +1 More generally: You can just ignore the date portion. If you want to meaningfully compare two `Date` objects that you're only storing time info in, be sure they're set to the same date (e.g., `1/1/1970` or similar).

Comment: But I want this repersentation in a Date object.

Comment: @Anu it uses `toString()` method to represent the data and which is hard coded you can't change the code to change the format output in `toString()`

Comment: My problem is that I have string having both time and date value. I need to get the time value and store it as date object and then use that date object in TimeSeries graph

Comment: parse the string (having both date and time) to `Date` using SimpleDateFormat, set it to calendar, access each field for example `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);` and do the required thing